# Varnish and no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0

Tags: cache, varnish

I am using Varnish with **Magento 2**.
I see that cache works (but for a short time) since I have the X cache: hit. And the **TTFB** is really good (**40ms**).

But I have `*no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0*` on the header for each page.
My problem is that the varnish cache works for only a short time..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value `no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0` for `Cache-Control` that you see only applies to browser caches, which instructs Magento HTML to not be cached by them.

That `Cache-Control` that you're seeing is emitted by [Varnish VCL](https://gist.github.com/dvershinin/de91aa78a96ae9f6e8d2950b3e1463a4#file-magento-vcl-L126). This is fine, and this value does *not* make Varnish cache less effective. This is only meant for browsers.

Varnish will use a different `Cache-Control`, emitted by Magento itself. Varnish cache lifetime depends on the [TTL setting](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html) you have in Magento backend.

You can access Magento HTTP headers (by doing `curl` against the proper port) directly and you'll see that the `Cache-Control` emitted by it is different, typically one day:

`Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400`. This is what Varnish sees and uses to define how long it caches public pages.

To recap:

- `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0` is to be expected unless you're checking Magento headers directly
- To cache things longer by Varnish, adjust the TTL in Magento settings